# Getting Month Names From Current Month to April

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How can I get The months names from Current month to April only using SQL

Ex:-if the current month is July then I want the month names from July to April.

Current month should be the running month.

Any function or something like that....(I need to get the data from Db for those months)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
WITH Dates AS
(
    SELECT GETDATE() D
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,D) FROM Dates WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,D)!=4
)
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,D) [Month Name] FROM Dates
```

**Result**

```
Month Name
------------------------------
September
October
November
December
January
February
March
April
```

Comment: Thanks it's Working,One more question how can pass these values to a Sp for getting the data

Comment: One thing for the above query if i want to get the month names by Year means if i pass 2017 then i need to get all the months

Comment: It looks like another question. Please don't change requirements in comments. Let other see correlation between question and answer. If you need this data in stored procedure, use this fragment in procedure, pass as table valued parameter or as collection is JSON/XML. Second comment: what do you mean by 'month by year' and get 'all months'? January to December? To April?